# array changing to integer

Tags: javascript, meteor

This Meteor server code suppose to append an object to an array and update the collection with the new array or an empty array if it does not exist.

Later in the code `removeFromPendingArr` gets called.
But the mongo shell is showing the value of the array to be 1 and not an array [] either empty or filled.
Any idea why and how to fix it? thx

```
'addToPendingArr': function (myObj) {
      let results = [];
      let pendingArr = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: ab.userIdForAB()}).myArr;

      if (typeof pendingArr === 'object') {
        results = pendingArr.push(myObj);
        Meteor.users.update({_id: ab.userIdForAB()}, {$set: {myArr: results}});
      }
      return results;
    },


'removeFromPendingArr': function (xxx) {
    let results = [];
    let pendingArr = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: ab.userIdForAB()}).myArr;

      if (typeof pendingArr === 'object' && pendingArr.length > 0) {
        results = pendingArr.filter(y => y.mark !== xxx);
      }

      Meteor.users.update({_id: ab.userIdForAB()}, {$set: {myArr: results}});
      return results;
    },
```

Comment: `results = pendingArr.push(myObj);` - results in `results` being the new length of the array -see ["Documentation"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push?v=control#Return_value)

Comment: I see. would you like to post the fix? thx

Comment: so, you can't figure it out? use `pendingArr` where you've used `results` (later in the code) - oh, not that easy because results should be an array ... how about you figure it out, it's not rocket surgery once you know results is not what you think it is, use what you need to use

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks, I already fixed it. Your posting will allow me to accept your solution. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use $push and $pull from Mongo?

```
'addToPendingArr': function (myObj) {
    Meteor.users.update(
        { _id: ab.userIdForAB() },
        { $push: { myArr: myObj } }
    );
}

'removeFromPendingArr': function (xxx) {
    Meteor.users.update(
        { _id: ab.userIdForAB() },
        { $pull: { myArr: xxx } }
    );
}
```